# Please verify my solution to $x^{1/x}=0$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

> Please check if I have done any mistakes in solving the equation
> $$x^{1/x}=0$$

Taking the natural logarithm on both sides, we get
$$\frac{1}{x}\ln{x} = -\infty \tag1$$

On further simplification, the equation becomes
$$-\ln{x} \cdot e^{-\ln(x)} = \infty \tag2$$
and taking the Lambert $W$ function on both sides we get
$$-\ln{x} = \infty \quad\text{or}\quad\ln{x} = -\infty \quad\text{or}\quad x = 0 \tag3$$
which means that $$0^{1/0}=0 \tag4$$

However, we can't conclude that $0^0 = 0$.

I also checked WolframAlpha which says $\sqrt[0]{0} = 0$. If I have made any mistakes, please correct me.

Comment: You cannot simply 'take the log of 0'. Notice that if $x\neq 0$ then $x^{1/x} \neq 0$. Moreover, if $x=0$ then the function $x^{1/x}$ is not defined. So there are no solutions to your equation

Comment: You can find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}x^{1/x}$  since for $0<x<1$ you have $0 < x^{1/x}<x$  so it is indeed $0$, but that does not mean $0^{1/0}$ is meaningful in itself

Comment: $a^b$ is never zero, except when $a=0$ and $b$ is positive and finite.